# How to remove all inherited CSS formatting for a table?

Tags: css, inheritance, css-tables

I have a table which has a certain style due to the CSS file for the page (it has blue borders, etc...).

Is there a simple way to remove the CSS for that specific table?
I was thinking something along the lines of a command like:

```
style="nostyle"
```

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this.

From [Eric Meyer's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: of course if you want to leave the css in place for the rest of the page, use an id or encapsulate with some container element
`#myTable table, caption, tbody, ...`
or
`.mySpanId table, caption, tbody, ...`

Comment: You need also to add `width: auto; height: auto`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sure you unset the CSS for all properties you can use the following:

```
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    all: unset;
}
```

MDN Documentation on the `all` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Answer (score 3):

Use a CSS reset like the [YUI CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Comment: Is there anything similar for JQuery?

Comment: @RichardOD: YUI CSS reset doesn't require any javascript. It is CSS-only. So it will work with jQuery.

Comment: @Kristof Oh yeah- I didn't noticed that first. I just assumed YUI was JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for something like this on a website that used both [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/) and the [tablesorter plugin](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), for a table inside a tablesorter table. While some of the answers here helped, it wasn't enough, especially since tablesorter uses :hover and jquery ui uses corner rounding, etc. Here is what I came up with:

I declared a class that when applied to a table will clean it up to some sensible defaults. It's imperative that this css is declared before any other classes it may need to clean up for, ie `<link>` to it or put it in a `<style>` tag at the top of your `<head>` section.

```css
.defaulttable {
  display: table;
}
.defaulttable thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
.defaulttable tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.defaulttable tfoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
.defaulttable tbody>tr:hover,
.defaulttable tbody>tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.defaulttable tbody>tr:hover>td,
.defaulttable tbody>tr>td {
  display: table-cell;
}
.defaulttable,
.defaulttable tbody,
.defaulttable tbody>tr:hover,
.defaulttable tbody>tr,
.defaulttable tbody>tr:hover>td,
.defaulttable tbody>tr>td,
.defaulttable tbody>tr:hover>th,
.defaulttable tbody>tr>th,
.defaulttable thead>tr:hover>td,
.defaulttable thead>tr>td,
.defaulttable thead>tr:hover>th,
.defaulttable thead>tr>th,
.defaulttable tfoot>tr:hover>td,
.defaulttable tfoot>tr>td,
.defaulttable tfoot>tr:hover>th,
.defaulttable tfoot>tr>th {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  empty-cells: show;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  table-layout: auto;
  caption-side: top;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Then simply apply the class to the table you want "defaulted":

```
<table class="defaulttable and whatever else you want">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This will appear with sensible defaults.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```