# CSS for cross-site widget, best practice?

Tags: javascript, css

So I've got code that people can cut+paste a widget into their site with (similar to google analytics or the Google maps plugin, if you've seen those).

I've got a whole area that needs to be styled somehow. Now, I can either do this by manually reading config data from an object like

```
var x = {idWhatever: {bg-color: red, etc....}}
```

Or I could `document.appendChild("style")`

Or I could inline all the css (I'd rather not).

Whatever happens, I can't be messing up other people's pages when this gets dropped in.

Any thoughts on the best way to deal with this?

edit: in theory, I may be able to use the data-uri to send the CSS in the same request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you carefully choose element classnames and ids such that they are all prefixed with the name of your widget (like `<myWidget>_mainDiv` and `.<myWidget>_headerText`).  Then make sure your styles are only targeting elements with (or at least, elements within elements with) these ids/classnames.

Then include your stylesheet either using the approach described [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) or with the `document.appendChild("style")` method.  Ideally you want to keep your CSS in its own file, or at least somewhere where you can still write and maintain it like CSS.  Which you can't really do if you stuff it inside of some object or if you inline it.

Comment: If it's not in an iframe, how would you handle inherit styles?

Comment: you can always implement a reset for elements within your "master css class"

Comment: @BrunoLM  - You mean, getting rid of styles that are inherited from CSS on the page?  Personally I probably wouldn't, and would leave that task up to the person integrating with my widget.  I see the role of the widget developer as having to provide a set of default styles that look good assuming no other styles are being applied to the widget elements.  The end-user can override and tweak those styles as they like.  Otherwise, the only solution I see is to [set explicit values for *every* commonly used CSS attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968895) on the outermost element.

Answer (score 1):

Give people two options:

1. Styles passed as a parameter (*object*).
2. Styles applied using your classnames.

In the first case you probably know what to do.

In the second case, add meaningful class names, as @aroth suggests in the answer (so you minimize risk of interfering with classes applied on the page that implements your widget).

It could look like this:

1. If someone does not give style parameter, then default styles are used. If not, then
2. If he gives any styles, these styles overwrite appropriate styles. If not, then
3. If he passes eg. `false` instead of styles parameter, then do not apply any styles and rely on CSS classes and trust that user will apply styles by himself.