# Removing table style with css class

Tags: html, css

I want a class that will remove all style on a table, but I can't get it working:

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css1.css" media="all" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css2.css" media="all" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css3.css" media="all" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css4.css" media="all" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/css5.css" media="print" />

     <style>
        .nostyle table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          outline: 0;
          font-size: 100%;
          vertical-align: baseline;
          background: transparent;
        }
     </style>

   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="nostyle">
        <table>
            <!-- more table properties -->
        </table>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work :/

I got the code from: [How to remove all inherited CSS formatting for a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968895/how-to-remove-all-inherited-css-formatting-for-a-table)

Comment: Can you explain your definition of "this doesn't work" ?

Comment: What's your actual goal with this?

Comment: @AlexW There is still style applied to the table.. like margin, borders and other stuff.

Comment: @DavidThomas I want to have a table without any style.

Comment: So, which properties are still present that are causing problems?

Comment: If you are using CSS then why don't you just not use tables? A div doesn't have any table styles and would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `#nostyle`, but it should be `.nostyle`. Periods are for `class`es, hashtags are for `id`s. I would just replace `#nostyle table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td` with `*` to apply those styles to everything in your document.

Comment: Oops, sorry that was a typo when I rewrote this code in stack overflow, that didn't fix the problem, but using `*` did! I changed it to `.noclass * {` and it worked! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Note that your selector specifically selects `.nostyle table`, but selects any `th`, `td` and others. To fix that, it should look like `.nostyle table, .nostyle caption, .nostyle tbody ...`.

Currently, if there is a more specific selector in any of your CSS files, it will probably overrule your generic css for each element but the table itself.

Also, some advice, learn to use FireBug or the built-in developer tools of any browser to inspect which styles exist on each element and to read where they came from. It really helps you to figure out problems like this yourself.

Comment: ahh this makes sense, thats why as suggested below `.noclass * {`  works correctly.

Comment: Yup. Tricky indeed. :) That's where those tools are really handy, a necessity I might say. :)

Comment: This solution of `.nostyle table, .nostyle caption, .nostyle tbody, .nostyle tfoot, .nostyle thead, .nostyle tr, .nostyle th, .nostyle td {` works a little better because it doesn't disable style of content inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

You really should probably be looking into using one of the standard CSS resets (see popular ones here http://www.cssreset.com/)

Just include the reset file as the FIRST linked stylesheet.

These will rest not only table styles (some of which you have missed in your rule) but styles for other elements as well.  This gives you a more predictable cross-browser development experience with regards to CSS.

Comment: In addition to other problems with CSS resets, they are a manifestly wrong approach here, since they *impose* style on elements, and here the goal is “table with no style”.

Comment: It depends on the kind of reset. Some reset elements to a generic default style and others remove as much as possible, even removing bold and italic from `b` and `i` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Either,

Change the div 'class="NoStyle"' to 'id="noStyle"'

or

Change the css to

```
.nostyle table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td { etc...
```

You're trying to apply an ID style to a class . . .

Answer (score 0):

What you need is create a css rule that applies to the table only if it has a specific class. Instead of:

```
table { ... }
```

use:

```
.table-styled {
     ...
}

.table-styled td {
     ...
}
```

So if you need to clear styles it's only depends on removing the `.table-styled` class of the table element.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get “a table without any style” is to use a table without any CSS that might affect it.

In your code, you are not removing any style with your `style` element, you are *adding* style. For example, setting padding to zero on `td` elements changes the rendering from common (and more or less recommended) browser defaults. So you would get a table *with* style.

If the external style sheets contain settings that may affect the table or its descendants, then you need to remove those settings or the `link` elements.

If you actually meant to ask how to make the rendering of a table *simple* (i.e., using simple style), as it seems, then it’s something to be asked as a new question, and you should define what you regard as “simple” (which would be more than half of the work).