# Dismiss css for one table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to dismiss one .css file for one table or div in the html, and for everything inside that tag.

I made some research but couldnt really find anything...

Comment: Try the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968895/how-to-remove-all-inherited-css-formatting-for-a-table)

Comment: It is not clear what you need, if you need to override a specific set of STYLES for that table/div, you could remove the classes they use. i.e. give the table an id, and [un]assign classes as you need them, you could use jQuery for that.

Comment: You can't just ignore rules I think, that's the whole point of CASCADING style sheets. I'd suggest you create a basic CSS class that sets your layout stuff to normal again for that particular table.

Comment: Please show your HTML

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to exclude any elements from the styles of the page.

To keep the rules from applying, you either need to override each style for those elements, or change the selectors for the rules so that they no longer apply to that element.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will simply overwrite the table, div styles like this

.myCssClass table {
}

Answer (score 0):

In a preprocessor

```
table * {
   //use some reset
   //additional overrides if you need too
}
```

Best solution is to modify your rules, or worst use an iframe :/